# SQLite3 explain query plan (raspberry PI)

Tags: sqlite, raspberry-pi

My development os is Linux(raspberry pi).
I installed sqlite3 and it is latest version.

**explain query plan** returns value
for example

```
sqlite> explain query plan select * from test_table
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE test_table (~100000 rows)
```

but my result is 
:

```
sqlite> explain query plan select * from test_table
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE test_table
```

`(~100000 rows)` is not shown.

what is problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) says:

> Warning: The data returned by the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN command is intended for interactive debugging only. The output format may change between SQLite releases.

You are using another SQLite release, and the output format indeed changed.